# Zoom, Gallery mode - force to always show users with video first, and then users without videos

Tags: ios, zoom.app

Most times Zoom (on iPad) in Gallery mode shows all users with videos first, and then users without videos.

But sometimes Zoom shuffles users with videos with users without videos.
This is very uncomfortable for me.
I seeking for a way to force Zoom always show all users with videos, and then all users without videos.
Searching Google didnt give any results, and inspecting Zoom settings also didnt give result.

Can you tell me please is there a way to force described behaviour in Zoom?

Answer (score 0):

There is only the option to show both users with video and those without or to not show those without video.  Tap the Gear in Zoom main App window or the ellipsis (...) button while on a meeting and turn off Show Non-Video Participants. You can always tap the Participants icon while in a meeting to view all participants.

It works this way on Mac and Windows too. Unless Zoom changes the behavior it will remain this way.